# Pyspark Cassandra - Create correct User Defined Type (UDT) for spark dataframe column with type "struct"

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

My spark dataframe has the following schema:

```
root
 |-- a: string (nullable = true)
 |-- b: long (nullable = true)
 |-- c: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- c1: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- c2: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- c3: long (nullable = true)
```

I'm trying to create a UDT in Cassandra keyspace to cater for column c. This new UDT will then be used to create Cassandra table to store my dataframe.

However, I keep encountering syntax error with my CQL. My CQL is:

```
"CREATE TYPE IF NOT EXISTS keyspace.my_udt(list<element frozen<c1 text, c2 double, c3 bigint>>);"
```

Error message is:

```
SyntaxException: <Error from server: code=2000 [Syntax error in CQL query] message="line 1:50 no viable alternative at input '<' (... NOT EXISTS keyspace .my_udt(list[<]...)">
```

I'm not familiar with CQL at all. Could someone help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE TYPE IF NOT EXISTS keyspace.my_udt(c1 text, c2 double, c3 bigint);

CREATE TABLE example (id uuid,elements list<FROZEN <my_udt>>,primary key(id));
```

[UDT in Cassandra](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_using/useCreateUDT.html)

Answer (score 1):

You need to have following definition for user-defined type (see [documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/cql/cql/cql_reference/cql_commands/cqlCreateType.html)):

```
CREATE TYPE IF NOT EXISTS my_udt(c1 text, c2 double, c3 bigint);
```

And the table should be:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table(a text, b bigint, c frozen<list<my_udt>>, primary key(a));
```